# App using Accelerometer in Android

Tags: android

I am biggener in android. I am trying to implement a fitness app that can keep track of the running speed and running distance in Android. How can i calculate the above mentioned things ?

Comment: GPS. Accelerometer will not give you this information. You can try counting steps with it, but not the speed/distance.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could analyse windows of accelerometer data and count the number of peaks and the forces of those to determine running. Then, if the user has entered an average step distance, that could give an equation of distance.

Would be a lot easier using GPS as it provides the speed directly.

You might be interested in this library: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation I recently added Activity Recognition, which can tell you whenever a user starts running. Might take a little while from one begins to run before the phone 'knows' that as being the activity, though.